# aboout the difference between window.location and window.open

Tags: javascript, w3c

i find that when the location attribute is set ,the page will  not redirect util the javascript run over, but the window.open will run right now.
why?
is there some documents about this??
below is test codes..

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = ("http://www.baidu.com");
window.open('http://google.com');
//alert(1);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://pic5.bbzhi.com/fengjingbizhi/zhongguolvyoufengguanggaoqingbizhi/zhongguolvyoufengguanggaoqingbizhi_448610_9.jpg?q=1"
/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`window.open` opens a **new** window/tab while modifying `location.href` redirects the **current** page.

The reason why the redirect does not happen until your script finished is simply that the browser pretty much won't do *anything* while a script is running - it's not a multithreaded environment.

Comment: but a new window will be opened  once the rode window.open runs.